# How to make AJAX request to SQL, and change what's displayed on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have this code to display a user's name:

```
<div><?php echo 'My name is ' . '<span id="output">' . $_SESSION['firstname'] . '</span>' ?></div>
```

I'd like to change what's displayed in `<span id="output"></span>` when a user changes their profile.

This is what I use to change their profile data in the database (shortened to only include what's needed):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
        $profile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $update = "UPDATE users SET firstname = '$firstname' WHERE username = '$username'";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $update);
            if (mysqli_query($connect, $update)) {
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
                echo 'Profile updated successfully';
            }
}
```

The thing is, I don't know how to change the "output" to the new $_SESSION['firstname'] without refreshing the page.

I would assume that I'd need to use JQuery's ajax function, but I'm not sure how to specifically use this function to get it done.

Comment: If you move your PHP code to above your HTML it would be fine. You should try and move any php logic, especially form submissions, to before you open the <html> tag. That would make it update the session value before you've displayed it and you would be fine.

Comment: @Brett Oh wow, I guess I just didn’t look at that problem in that way. Thanks!

Comment: It is a `very very ..... very very very ..... .... very very` **bad** idea to search on names this way. *Change your db structure*. Each user should have their own `AUTO INCREMENT`. Store that in a session var, and change user data on that ID. What if 2 people share the same name?

Comment: @Xorifelse yeah my db is different. Each user has a unique username with a unique auto-incrementing ID. I just excluded everything here to remove all the clutter from my question.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are wrong with the code. Besides that point here is a simple ajax request.

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'yourscript.php',
    data: {firstname: $('#firstname').val()},
    success: function(data){
      $('#firstname').html(data);
    }
  });
})
```

And for PHP:

```
# 'yourscript.php',

if(isset($firstname = $_POST['firstname'])){
  // do your stuff.

  echo 'your new data you want to display';
} else {
  echo 'something went wrong';
}
```